# Media Files not Loading on pythonanywhere.com (Django)

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

website: https://willpeoples1.pythonanywhere.com/

I deployed a personal portfolio project using pythonanywhere.com's server and my instructor sent me a video explaining why my media files weren't loading properly (https://d.pr/v/RARFcF). However, I couldn't understand why he was telling me to change the pathname of the image in my HTML b/c I am using a template in the img-tag. Any clue where I should go from here? Thanks

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URLS = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from portfolio import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

home page HTML file:

```
<div class="conatainer text-center">
      {% for proj in Projects %} 
      <hr>
      <h2>{{ proj.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ proj.description }}</p>
      <a href="{{ proj.url }}" target="_blank"><img src= "{{ proj.image.url }}" target="_blank" height="300" width="300"></a>
      <br>
      <br>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: instead of us watching video explain the problem with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
For example show us your template and media settings

Comment: There is a help page on PythonAnywhere that you can use to debug issues with static files here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles/

Answer (score 0):

This is all set. There was a spelling mistake in my settings.py file. I wrote "MEDIA_URLS" instead of "MEDIA_URL".